# Alpine Linux sometimes DNS is not resolved

Tags: resolv.conf, alpine-linux

Sometimes when I run the commands:

```
sudo apk update && sudo apk upgrade
```

Over Alpine linux fails to update the packages even if connected to internet. But if I do `sudo su "echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf"` I manage to dowload them. But this solution:

- Causes me frustration I need to set dns all over the time.
- Sometimes `/etc/resolv.conf` gets overriden by itself.

How I can have a more permanent solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve the problem by installing the `dhclient` package. For the last time enable Google's DNS servers by runing for the last time:

```
sudo su "echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf"
```

Then run this cocktail of commands:

```
sudo apk update && sudo apk upgrade && sudo apk add dhclient
```

In order to get the fresh packages and install the `dhclient`. Then configure the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and put the following:

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;

prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

And restart the networking:

```
sudo rc-service networking restart
```

Optionally you can confirm that works if you run:

```
sudo reboot
```

In either case you can confirm that dns is resolved by pinging the google.

```
ping google.com
```

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr

1. Open file **/etc/udhcpc/udhcpc.conf** with a text editor.
   If the file is missing you just have to create it (and probably its containing folder).
2. Append line

   ```
   RESOLV_CONF=no
   ```

Done.

Found here: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Udhcpc

---

The accepted answer wasn't satisfying in my case for

- it's causing lots of stuff to be pasted without knowing what it's doing,
- it's requiring installation of additional software and
- it's just prepending given DNS server(s) to whatever it is writing into **/etc/resolv.conf** nonetheless instead of replacing it.

I'm sure there are more instructions on how to make dhclient replace stuff instead of prepending things, but that's too much research and headache for something as simple as preventing DHCP from replacing **/etc/resolv.conf** at all.

Comment: Seems it should be RESOLV_CONF="no". Did not work without "" in my case.

Comment: In my case omitting the quotation marks is working just fine. The file is included by **/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script** using **/bin/sh** so quotation marks should not make a difference unless the value contains whitespace or other functional characters of shell which doesn't apply to `no`. I assume there was a different issue in your case or maybe your version is different. In my case it's Alpine 3.10.3.

Answer (score 0):

Udhcpc need /etc/udhcpc/udhcpc.conf, accessible by all, with a single line  `dns="ns1 ns2"`

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).